# Cohens_d error due to non-numeric vector...but where is it?

Tags: r, vector, rstatix

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Cannot compute effect size for a non-numeric vector.
```

When I try to calculate `cohens_d` (RStatix) in R Studio using this code:

```
> # Calculate (Cohen's D) effect size
> Cohen <- LST_Weather_dataset %>% 
+   group_by(Month, .add = FALSE) %>% 
+   cohens_d(
+     LST ~ TimePeriod, paired = TRUE
+     )
```

LST, Month and TimePeriod are all numeric:

```
> str(LST_Weather_dataset)
'data.frame':   456 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ Buffer        : int  100 200 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 ...
 $ Date          : Date, format: "0006-10-20" ...
 $ LST           : num  1.7 1.38 2.66 3.81 3.2 ...
 $ Month         : num  10 10 12 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ...
 $ Year          : int  2013 2013 2013 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 ...
 $ JulianDay     : int  279 279 359 10 42 74 106 122 170 202 ...
 $ TimePeriod    : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
...
```

The error persists if I remove `group_by`.

What am I missing?

**Edit**

Data requested in comments:

```
> test <- dput(LST_Weather_dataset[1:300, c("Month", "LST", "TimePeriod")])
structure(list(Month = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12), LST = c(-0.2210116, -0.24720568, -0.26111535, 
-0.25316346, -0.30848301, -0.33180257, -0.27721127, -0.20766731, 
-0.14346835, -0.06433451, -0.02385345, -0.03473869, -0.0511723, 
-0.04610033, -0.03462484, -0.03734767, -0.04306532, -0.02964348, 
-0.01385088, -0.22618709, -0.2425393, -0.2541757, -0.25475207, 
-0.29917977, -0.36117768, -0.31852919, -0.28564376, -0.2359735, 
-0.12195752, -0.06586962, -0.05811313, -0.03766735, -0.02261001, 
-0.03555068, -0.05061729, -0.05351268, -0.02241539, -0.00981671, 
-0.22016505, -0.26550893, -0.29015481, -0.28068968, -0.3103153, 
-0.33183916, -0.2798485, -0.24933379, -0.23071591, -0.15598767, 
-0.0976511, -0.07922456, -0.06455107, -0.03039455, -0.00439505, 
-0.00427336, -0.01586557, -0.03632884, -0.02813621, -0.34759789, 
-0.40494336, -0.41258461, -0.38127643, -0.38749164, -0.43010968, 
-0.38592257, -0.31959701, -0.25699752, -0.17257249, -0.13109291, 
-0.11687805, -0.10309548, -0.0933909, -0.07803618, -0.06782885, 
-0.05547398, -0.02602688, -0.01469682, -0.16601023, -0.20167048, 
-0.18983419, -0.1591577, -0.15829101, -0.18991115, -0.15560403, 
-0.08758369, -0.0419441, 0.02094988, 0.06149603, 0.04233754, 
0.05957017, 0.08024451, 0.07646054, 0.05378477, 0.01491128, 0.02128012, 
0.01505348, -0.27509869, -0.29971987, -0.28898894, -0.26678469, 
-0.26546793, -0.2767395, -0.21621339, -0.13996242, -0.0772666, 
-0.01513719, 0.01099537, 0.00156385, 0.03741067, 0.05769562, 
0.05522714, 0.03726737, 0.00673056, -0.0086786, -0.00868214, 
-0.24094543, -0.27829062, -0.27762726, -0.26392197, -0.25151899, 
-0.2454435, -0.20808879, -0.15734442, -0.11566806, -0.07631076, 
-0.05374834, -0.06464258, -0.04748078, -0.04106418, -0.02877574, 
-0.04559453, -0.04936476, -0.03311713, -0.0184964, -0.161790125, 
-0.207325856, -0.202609595, -0.182737706, -0.176479067, -0.172051143, 
-0.115534666, -0.069043871, -0.045666582, -0.016103689, -0.0097142, 
-0.027125424, -0.031078945, -0.027668948, -0.038168329, -0.04902581, 
-0.049393072, -0.029093549, -0.016435892, -0.18777984, -0.22560193, 
-0.21353557, -0.19873006, -0.21000726, -0.19960744, -0.16449805, 
-0.12677822, -0.09319863, -0.05365756, -0.03196716, -0.03521089, 
-0.01844106, -0.01675121, -0.02673582, -0.0336761, -0.03909757, 
-0.02311188, -0.00841367, -0.06879569, -0.11193502, -0.11645102, 
-0.11313204, -0.1241938, -0.12764257, -0.09562478, -0.06360073, 
-0.03919549, -0.01310477, 0.00199091, -0.00299883, 0.00071001, 
-0.0009422, -0.01377567, -0.03184663, -0.0422166, -0.02251581, 
-0.00296154, -0.16582354, -0.19623703, -0.19219006, -0.16517101, 
-0.18704658, -0.15345162, -0.10262394, -0.08604339, -0.08749103, 
-0.06062491, -0.03485287, -0.0373792, -0.03525576, -0.04025037, 
-0.02994186, -0.03698465, -0.0445463, -0.03625804, -0.01916101, 
-0.32618398, -0.38494187, -0.37563704, -0.3362058, -0.33109373, 
-0.28774767, -0.23600731, -0.18341335, -0.14375045, -0.09224798, 
-0.06322383, -0.06435687, -0.04382372, -0.04243214, -0.04790463, 
-0.05992479, -0.05804111, -0.03623521, -0.01380783, 0.07521048, 
0.08923107, 0.04085175, 0.02369799, -0.01174092, -0.00924432, 
0.02309842, 0.03106341, 0.01589905, 0.02520586, 0.02755641, 0.01418465, 
0.03378753, 0.0356642, 0.03617703, 0.0236984, 0.01581965, 0.00092364, 
-0.00135577, -0.01808666, -0.02659894, -0.06659976, -0.07161127, 
-0.07336009, -0.05201086, -0.00927892, 0.02300103, 0.03837143, 
0.05036375, 0.06564468, 0.0600014, 0.06562315, 0.05419116, 0.04456497, 
0.01096535, -0.00228103, -0.00411322, -0.00017688, -0.06780171, 
-0.06119238, -0.07202179, -0.05932171, -0.09219981, -0.0933819, 
-0.0571732, -0.03830071, -0.02184744, 0.01698308, 0.02923943, 
0.01394951, 0.01748671, 0.01059124, -0.00520207, -0.02724512, 
-0.02908047, -0.01867358, -0.0086791, -0.02430298, -0.04431464, 
-0.0597082, -0.07027699, -0.09412717, -0.08051615, -0.04382819, 
-0.01872886, -0.00143456, 0.01274511, 0.02342804, 0.00065864, 
0.00322716, -0.00126722, -0.00821571), TimePeriod = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
"2"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 300L), class = "data.frame")
> Cohen <- test %>% 
+ #  group_by(TimePeriod) %>%
+   cohens_d(
+     LST ~ Month, paired = FALSE
+     )
Error: Cannot compute effect size for a non-numeric vector.
>
```

Comment: `?cohens_d` (from rstatix) mentions that the group (RHS of formula) should be a factor

Comment: I've tried using as.factor already - makes no difference where I use group_by or not - always get the error.

Comment: ... altough `cohens_d(mpg ~ cyl, data=mtcars)` works without cyl being a factor

Comment: Paired = FALSE makes no difference

Comment: I'll try another package and see where I get...

Comment: could you edit your question with enough of your data to reproduce the error please e.g. add `dput(LST_Weather_dataset[1:20, c("Month", "LST", "TimePeriod)])` (if that throws the same error)

Comment: Edited question to add data - 1:300 to get second value of TimePeriod in the sample.

Comment: Thank you for the update. This code runs without error for me . `packageVersion("rstatix")` == ` ‘0.7.0’`

Comment: Argh!  :)  So I've reset my environment, started from scratch, and still get the error.  How could I chase this down?  I have RStatix 0.7.0., too.

Comment: ```> is.numeric(LST_Weather_dataset$LST)
[1] TRUE
> is.numeric(LST_Weather_dataset$TimePeriod)
[1] FALSE
> is.numeric(LST_Weather_dataset$Month)
[1] TRUE```
```

Comment: If I just load rstatix, the data, and call cohens_d in a completely new script it fails.

Comment: good you found an answer strangecharm. It would still be good to chase down why this is happening.Can you try starting from a fresh R session e.g. don't load any previous workspaces or any other packages, then load only rstatix and run only the data and code in your edited question. I'm thinking there may be a clash somewhere

Comment: With my limited experience with R that was what I was thinking, but I couldn't see where.  That said, exploring the persistence of packages loaded this morning I've found out that I almost certainly didn't have a completely clean environment.  I'll do what you suggest later on today.

Comment: Cleared R Studio environment with ```rm(list = ls(envir = globalenv()), envir = globalenv()); if(!is.null(dev.list())) dev.off(); gc(); cat("\014")```

Loaded `rstatix`, and checked loaded packages with ```library(rstatix)
(.packages())```
Test ran without errors.

Comment: Going back to the original script, packages loaded when the error occurred are ```> (.packages())
 [1] "ez"        "forcats"   "stringr"   "dplyr"     "purrr"     "readr"     "tidyr"     "tibble"    "tidyverse" "ggpubr"   
[11] "ggplot2"   "rstatix"   "stats"     "graphics"  "grDevices" "utils"     "datasets"  "methods"   "base"     ```.  How do you go about finding the clash?  Trial and error?  I guess then flag it up on Github as a bug?

Comment: rstatix imports a lot of packages; see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstatix/index.html so you would expect to see this list. These will in turn have dependencies. If you add the results of `sessionInfo()` to your question, I can compare package version numbers. (ps to open a fresh R session, you can use `R --vanilla` at the terminal but not sure how to do it using a gui. When you start R normally, you will get a message if loading a previous workspace. You can remove this by removing .Rdata and .rds files from your working directory.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll post the `sessionInfo()` in the morning.

Comment: Too long for comment - additional answer below.

Comment: strangecharm; so it now works?

Comment: Not sure - I can't remember if I previously used the sample or the whole dataset.  I'll go back and look tomorrow (maybe Wednesday - depends on childcare).

Comment: ... no need . Seems likely was a (perhaps temporary) local issue, rather than a code /programming problem.

Comment: If that turns out not to be the case I'll update here.  Thanks for the guidance.  ATB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `effsize` package instead of `rstatix` the test ran successfully:

```
LST_Weather_dataset %>% group_by(Month, .add = FALSE)
# A tibble: 456 x 14
# Groups:   Month [12]
   Buffer Date         LST Month  Year JulianDay TimePeriod
    <int> <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
 1    100 2010-01-15 0.581     1  2010        15          1
 2    100 2010-02-16 0.971     2  2010        47          1
 3    100 2010-03-20 1.63      3  2010        79          1
 4    100 2011-04-24 2.14      4  2011       114          1
 5    100 2010-05-07 1.90      5  2010       127          1
 6    100 2010-06-08 3.32      6  2010       159          1
 7    100 2011-07-13 1.67      7  2011       194          1
 8    100 2010-08-11 2.74      8  2010       223          1
 9    100 2010-09-12 2.27      9  2010       255          1
10    100 2011-10-17 0.987    10  2011       290          1
# ... with 446 more rows, and 7 more variables: Humidity <dbl>,
#   Wind_speed <dbl>, Wind_gust <dbl>, Wind_trend <dbl>,
#   Wind_direction <dbl>, Pressure <dbl>, Pressure_trend <dbl>
> CohenD2 <- cohen.d(
+     LST ~ TimePeriod | Subject(Buffer), paired = TRUE
+     )
> CohenD2

Cohen's d

d estimate: 0.5875947 (medium)
95 percent confidence interval:
    lower     upper 
0.4328020 0.7423874 

> ungroup(LST_Weather_dataset)
# A tibble: 456 x 14
   Buffer Date         LST Month  Year JulianDay TimePeriod
    <int> <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
 1    100 2010-01-15 0.581     1  2010        15          1
 2    100 2010-02-16 0.971     2  2010        47          1
 3    100 2010-03-20 1.63      3  2010        79          1
 4    100 2011-04-24 2.14      4  2011       114          1
 5    100 2010-05-07 1.90      5  2010       127          1
 6    100 2010-06-08 3.32      6  2010       159          1
 7    100 2011-07-13 1.67      7  2011       194          1
 8    100 2010-08-11 2.74      8  2010       223          1
 9    100 2010-09-12 2.27      9  2010       255          1
10    100 2011-10-17 0.987    10  2011       290          1
# ... with 446 more rows, and 7 more variables: Humidity <dbl>,
#   Wind_speed <dbl>, Wind_gust <dbl>, Wind_trend <dbl>,
#   Wind_direction <dbl>, Pressure <dbl>, Pressure_trend <dbl>
> CohenD2 <- cohen.d(
+     LST ~ TimePeriod | Subject(Buffer), paired = TRUE
+     )
> CohenD2

Cohen's d

d estimate: 0.5875947 (medium)
95 percent confidence interval:
    lower     upper 
0.4328020 0.7423874
```

Grouping the data using group_by made no difference as | Subject() does this within the function.

Comment: Thanks @user20650 for your help with this.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Trying to chase down the error in rstatix - per user20650's comment above.

New session (via menu in R Studio) - dput() code above used to create `test` data.frame, rstatix loaded using `library(rstatix)`, then test run with

```
Cohen <- test %>% 
    group_by(TimePeriod) %>%
    cohens_d(LST ~ Month, paired = FALSE)
```

Test runs successfully:

```
> Cohen
# A tibble: 72 x 8
   .y.   group1 group2 effsize TimePeriod    n1    n2 magnitude 
 * <chr> <chr>  <chr>    <dbl> <fct>      <int> <int> <ord>     
 1 LST   1      2       0.704  1             19    19 moderate  
 2 LST   1      3       0.516  1             19    19 moderate  
 3 LST   1      4       0.669  1             19    19 moderate  
 4 LST   1      5       0.686  1             19    19 moderate  
 5 LST   1      6       1.10   1             19    19 large     
 6 LST   1      7      -0.480  1             19    19 small     
 7 LST   1      8       0.106  1             19    19 negligible
 8 LST   1      9       0.489  1             19    19 small     
 9 LST   1      10     -0.0644 1             19    19 negligible
10 LST   1      11      0.138  1             19    19 negligible
# ... with 62 more rows
```

Packages loaded as dependencies of `rstatix`, as listed using sessionInfo():

```
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rstatix_0.7.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] rstudioapi_0.13  magrittr_2.0.1   tidyselect_1.1.1 R6_2.5.1         rlang_0.4.12     carData_3.0-4   
 [7] fansi_0.5.0      car_3.0-12       dplyr_1.0.7      tools_4.1.2      broom_0.7.10     utf8_1.2.2      
[13] cli_3.1.0        DBI_1.1.2        ellipsis_0.3.2   abind_1.4-5      assertthat_0.2.1 tibble_3.1.6    
[19] lifecycle_1.0.1  crayon_1.4.2     purrr_0.3.4      tidyr_1.1.4      vctrs_0.3.8      glue_1.6.0      
[25] compiler_4.1.2   pillar_1.6.4     generics_0.1.1   backports_1.4.1  pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

Packages with pending updates in my installation of R Studio:

```
> old.packages()
               Package          LibPath                                               Installed Built   ReposVer 
broom          "broom"          "C:/Users/prmon/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.1" "0.7.10"  "4.1.2" "0.7.11" 
carData        "carData"        "C:/Users/prmon/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.1" "3.0-4"   "4.1.1" "3.0-5"  
datawizard     "datawizard"     "C:/Users/prmon/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.1" "0.2.1"   "4.1.2" "0.2.2"  
distributional "distributional" "C:/Users/prmon/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.1" "0.2.2"   "4.1.2" "0.3.0"  
esquisse       "esquisse"       "C:/Users/prmon/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.1" "1.0.2"   "4.1.2" "1.1.0"  
fansi          "fansi"          "C:/Users/prmon/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.1" "0.5.0"   "4.1.0" "1.0.0"  
gert           "gert"           "C:/Users/prmon/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.1" "1.4.3"   "4.1.2" "1.5.0"  
httpuv         "httpuv"         "C:/Users/prmon/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.1" "1.6.4"   "4.1.2" "1.6.5"  
insight        "insight"        "C:/Users/prmon/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.1" "0.14.5"  "4.1.2" "0.15.0" 
RcppParallel   "RcppParallel"   "C:/Users/prmon/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.1" "5.1.4"   "4.1.2" "5.1.5"  
renv           "renv"           "C:/Users/prmon/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.1" "0.14.0"  "4.1.1" "0.15.0" 
SuppDists      "SuppDists"      "C:/Users/prmon/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.1" "1.1-9.5" "4.1.2" "1.1-9.7"
Matrix         "Matrix"         "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.2/library"                  "1.3-4"   "4.1.2" "1.4-0"  
               Repository                            
broom          "https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib"
carData        "https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib"
datawizard     "https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib"
distributional "https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib"
esquisse       "https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib"
fansi          "https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib"
gert           "https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib"
httpuv         "https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib"
insight        "https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib"
RcppParallel   "https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib"
renv           "https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib"
SuppDists      "https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib"
Matrix         "https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib"
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer will work to calculate the desired effect size statistic, but I thought I'd add a possible cause of the initial issue, having run into it today and spent some time diagnosing it.

The error:

> Error: Cannot compute effect size for a non-numeric vector.

is associated with the `cohens_d()` function in the `effectsize` package rather than the `rstatix` package strangecharm (OP) was using. The `effectsize::cohens_d()` function takes a formula or vector as its first argument, but the `rstatix::cohens_d()` function takes the dataframe as its first argument. Thus, if strangecharm had loaded `effectsize` prior to execution (and *after* `rstatix`, so that the `cohens_d()` function was masked), the syntax:

```
# Calculate (Cohen's D) effect size
Cohen <- LST_Weather_dataset %>% 
   group_by(Month, .add = FALSE) %>% 
   cohens_d(
     LST ~ TimePeriod, paired = TRUE
     )
```

would have fed the function an invalid first argument (namely the grouped dataset LST_Weather_dataset rather than the LST vector). Running:

```
# Calculate (Cohen's D) effect size
Cohen <- LST_Weather_dataset %>% 
   group_by(Month, .add = FALSE) %>% 
   rstatix::cohens_d(
     LST ~ TimePeriod, paired = TRUE
     )
```

instead should fix the problem if this was the cause.

This is consistent with user20650's comment that the example code ran on their computer and with stangecharm's finding that starting a completely new session and running only the specific, relevant commands fixed the issue (if I understood that correctly), as in these cases, the effectsize package would not have been loaded prior to execution.